# Publicar aplicativo privado na Google Play sem ser empresa

Tags: google-play

gostaria de saber se é possível publicar um aplicativo na Google Play para determinados usuários através de seus emails, queria algo parecido como quando lançamos aplicativos para testes betas e alfas e adicionamos os emails dos testadores que poderão visualizar e baixar o app, enquanto procurava por algo nesse sentindo achei o Google Apps for Work mas pelo o que eu entendi, isso é para liberar o aplicativo para e-mail com o domínio da empresa e não é isso que eu desejo, quero poder disponibilizar o aplicativo para qualquer gmail.
Se alguém poder me ajudar aprecio muito, desde já muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa tarde Maycon,

Você pode distribuir seu aplicativo através de um canal privado, não é necessário ser uma empresa.

Para isso é necessário ter uma conta de desenvolvedor (a normal mesmo) a única ressalva é que o seu domínio **NÃO** pode ser Gmail.

Quando você publicar no canal privado, somente usuários com o mesmo domínio que o seu poderão acessar esse canal.

**Como publicar:**

1. Se ainda não o tiver feito, seu administrador precisará ativar o Canal privado do seu domínio.
2. Faça login no seu Console do desenvolvedor do Google Play.
3. Selecione Todos os apps All applications.
4. Selecione um app.
5. Selecione Preços e distribuição.
6. Em "Distribuição restrita", selecione Disponibilizar este app somente para os usuários do meu nome de domínio. Você só verá essa opção se suas configurações do Admin Console estiverem ajustadas corretamente.
7. Na parte superior da página, clique em Salvar rascunho (novos apps) ou Enviar atualização (apps existentes).

Dica: caso o proprietário da conta de desenvolvedor não esteja no seu domínio e a opção "Restringir distribuição" não seja exibida, você precisará transferir seu app para uma conta de desenvolvedor no seu domínio.

Fonte: [Support Google.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2623322?hl=pt-BR)

Então mesmo sem ser empresa, você pode criar um email com um domínio próprio e distribuir o acesso a quem lhe interessar.

(Lembrando que tudo pertinente a preços e condições são iguais ao da store normal, você pode cobrar e ser cobrado da mesma forma).

Comment: Entendi Lucas, então o único jeito é assim mesmo pensei que podia ter outro, mas muito obrigado, tenha um ótimo dia.

Comment: Se lhe ajudou, por favor aceite a resposta como certa

Comment: Uma outra alternativa, é distribuir aparelhos com Android 5.0+ e usar o Google Play Work, você separa o sistema em "dois" sendo um pessoal e outro corporativo, assim você controla o que o usuário instala no corporativo